# How to add an item to the gnome menu that starts gedit as root?

Tags: ubuntu, root, gedit, gksudo

I right clicked the gnome menu and clicked on "Edit menus"

Then I clicked on "New item".

- Type: `Application`
- Name: `gedit as root`
- Command: `gksudo gedit`
- Comment: `Launch gedit as root.`

When I click it, the `gksudo` dialog appears as expected. But then... nothing.

How should I be doing this? (From the menu - I know it's trivial from the terminal)

Comment: W​hich distro​?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit.

Comment: Never mind. There were nonfunctioning instances of gedit already running. I killed them and now it works as written above.